# Postgres pg_dump getting very slow while copying large objects

Tags: postgresql, blob, pg-dump

I was performing a pg_dump operation on a postgres (v9) database of size around 80Gb.
The operation never seemed to finish even when trying the following:

- running a FULL VACUUM before dumping
- dumping the db into a directory-format archive (using -Fd)
- without compression (-Z 0)
- dumping the db into a directory in parallel (tried up to 10 threads -j 10)

When using the --verbose flag I saw that the most of the logs are related to creating/executing large objects.

When I tried dumping each table on its own (pg_dump -t table_name) the result was fast again (in minutes) but when restoring the dump to another db, the application that uses the db started throwing exceptions regarding some resources not being found (they should've been in the db)
As in [Postgres pg_dump docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html) when using the -t flag the command will not copy blobs.

I added the flag -b (pg_dump -b -t table_name) and the operation went back to being slow.

So the problem I guess is with exporting the blobs in the db.

The number of blobs should be around 5 Million which can explain the slowness in general but the duration of execution is lasting as long as 5 hours before killing the process manually.
The blobs are relatively small (Max 100 Kb per blob)

Is this expected? or is there something fishy going around?

Comment: What is the complete `pg_dump` command you are running?  Are you dumping across a network? What is the machine's specifications?  Add answers as update to question.

Comment: There are 7 different major versions that all start with '9'. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The slowness was due to high number of orphaned blobs

Apparently when launching a FULL VACUUM on a postgres database, it doesn't not remove orphaned large objects.

When I queried the amount of large objects in my database

```
select count(distinct loid) from pg_largeobject;

output:
151200997
```

The displayed amount from the query did not match the expected value. The expected amount of blobs should be around 5 Million in my case.

The table (the one that I created in the app) that references those blobs, in my case, is subject for frequent updates and postgres does not delete the old tuples (rows) but rather marks them as 'dead' and inserts the new ones. With each update to the table the old blob becomes no longer referenced by alive tuples, only by dead ones which makes it an orphaned blob.

Postgres has a dedicated command '[vacuumlo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/vacuumlo.html)' to vacuum orphaned blobs.

After using it (the vacuum took around 4h) the dump  operation became much faster. The new duration is around 2h (previsouly taking hours and hours without finishing)